# Reading XML nodes attribute as per user input

Tags: xml, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml, readxml

```
<Default>
<SharepointContentType id="SharePointContentType">

<name id="Test1"
         DisplayName="TestOne"
         SharepointGroup="Test1SPGp">
    </name>

<name id="Test2"
         DisplayName="TestTwo"
          SharepointGroup="Test2SPGp">
    </name>
.
.
.
.

</SharepointContentType>
.
.
.
.
<Default>
```

For the above schema i want to descend as, find a node where id is `SharePointContentType` than find tag `<name >` where id is `Test1`(user defined) and than fetch the value for the the element `SharepointGroup`

e.g if user input is `Test1` than out put should be `Test1SPGp` Kindly help i was trying to use linq and managed to code as below but could not succeed.

```
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(GetDefaultXMLFile());

    var feeds = from feed in xDoc.Descendants("name")
                where feed.Attribute("id").Equals("admin")
                select new
                {
                    fxfv = feed.Attribute("SharepointGroup").Value
                };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a mistake in where condition, see below:

feed.Attribute("id") returns XAttribute class so you can't use equals to compare to a string, but after Value property you can.

```
        var feeds = from feed in xDoc.Descendants("name")
                    where feed.Attribute("id").Value.Equals("Test1")
                    select new
                    {
                        fxfv = feed.Attribute("SharepointGroup").Value
                    };
```